# How to Print a single Button multiple times in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have to call single button multiple times using *ngFor .

But needed to do alternate solution .

Example:-

Button1 visible.

Button1 disable.

Button1 visible.

Button2 disable.

.
.

..
.
.

Want to do this using *ngFor and by using a single button .

Comment: Take a look at this example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-starter-xt5poe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **odd** and **even** keywords on *ngFor:

*even: boolean: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.*

*odd: boolean: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.*

(from the Angular API: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

You can find an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-odd-even?file=app%2Fapp.component.html